# Create path from Lat long on Three JS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

i am trying to implement pipe like structure based on geo coordinate , the data is a json format which look like this.

```
[
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10185525",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4629527"
},
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10181625",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4629827"
},
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10185525",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4629527"
},
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10181625",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4629827"
},
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10185525",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4329527"
},
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10181625",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4629827"
},
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10185525",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4629527"
},
{
    "LATITUDE": "55.10181625",
    "LONGITUDE": "-76.4629827"
}
```

]

i used this conversion method to create Three js Vector3

```
function convertLatLonToVec3(lat,lon) {
lat =  lat * Math.PI / 180.0;
lon = -lon * Math.PI / 180.0;
return new THREE.Vector3( 
    Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon),
    Math.sin(lat),
    Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon));
```

};
but this doesn't work really well. so is there any otherway to implement lat long on 3d plane

Comment: What do you mean with _"doesn't work really well"_?

Comment: i mean it doesn't throw any errors..or show anything....

Comment: you have latitude and logitude, but what radius?

Comment: latitude and logitude  are real ..earths radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) if you want to project points to a coordinate reference system.